# What's the correct grammar of the VM parameter for the tomcat 7 running within hotspot 7 in Linux

Tags: tomcat, sh

I found a strange issue, I have two application, and I set the JVM parameter with the grammar below, and everything is okay, however another application would fail to start with the following grammar.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m"
```

So we change the grammar to the following(adding the {}), then it is running ok.

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xms1g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m"
```

My question is what's the correct grammar , JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS ... or  JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} ? or it depends on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Java thing. This is part of a shell script, so depends on the grammar of a shell you're running.

E.g. for bash `${parameter}` and `$parameter` are the same. The option with curly braces are used in a more complex cases.

Please see [bash variable expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) for more info.